# Which tools can find unicode (UTF-8) text in files containing any form of normalization?

Tags: grep, find, unicode

I like to find international text, like "müller", or even chinese text, in files, no matter which unicode representation and case is used.

I.e, it should not matter whether the "ü" is stored in NFC or NFD format.

I'd think that grep could do this, but at least the version available on macOS 10.13.6 finds only one normalization form.

I'd expect that, with algorithms like Aho–Corasick that can search for alternatives of letters in words, it should not be so difficult to build a tree that includes every alternative form of a UTF8 character and then search for all combinations. Yet, at least the grep I tried doesn't do that.

Are there implementations of grep or other text find tools that can do this properly?

Comment: Is a pipeline through `uconv` reasonable?

Comment: You mean to preprocess the files I want to search? Maybe. The files are binary, and maybe lots of MB in size. Will that be fairly fast compared to the following find operation? Don't want this to go down by factor 10, but factor 2 would be okay.

Comment: I think you'll gonna need to match every form of the matched text, in case it's short, it wouldn't be too hard to find all its possible form. Trying to NFC all the data wouldn't work because NFC algorithm is not additive, NFC a large text segment is super inefficient

Comment: Is not clear what you are asking with _find international text_. Finding non-ASCII characters (like with `unihist`)? Words, like in `grep -o -E '\w+'`? Which unicode ranges do you consider _international_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue with a regex engine (PCRE2).

Basically, I convert, using my own written code, the user's search string into all possible UTF-8 and UTF-16 representations, and then combine them all into a single regex expression, as alternatives, and taking care to escape any character as necessary (e.g. the `00` bytes of UTF-16 chars are encoded as `\x00`).

The nature of regex, which builds a decision tree, makes the search then quite fast.

That lets me scan any binary file for the search string, no matter in which format it's encoded in the file.

Since I needed this feature in one of my own programs, I should have mentioned that programming solutions were also welcome (and then it'd have better belonged on the StackOverflow site).

Comment: Unless you share your code, that answer is not going to be very useful to anyone. Are you also taking into account the order in which characters are combined? Like `ū̳` as `uU+0304U+0333` vs `uU+0333U+0304` vs `U+016BU+0333`?

Comment: Since this is not a code related site, I think explaining the method is more helpful here. I only thought of adding precomposed and decomposed writings of the entire search string to the regex alternatives, but your case isn't known to me. Is that just an underline option for the letter ü, or what is that?

Comment: That's u with two combining characters. See also `u\u0304\u0308` `u\u0308\u0304` which actually have two different precomposed forms: (`U+01D5 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS AND MACRON` and `U+1E7B LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH MACRON AND DIAERESIS`). While both `C\u301\u327` and `C\u327\u301` give [`U+1E08 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C WITH CEDILLA AND ACUTE`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E1%B8%88) after canonical composition...